# how to use drop wizard in ubuntu on grails project

Tags: dropwizard

I am developing a grails project in that i want to use drop wizard for build manager. I have installed pre-requisites for drop-wizard like. java-7,maven and mysql.
  Now my question is, how to use drop wizard with my grails project.

If any one of you help me it will greate helpfull for me.

thanks in advance.